# Entity Framework 6.0.2 not working in Coded UI project on build machine

Tags: entity-framework, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to read values from a table using Entity Framework 6.0.2 in my Coded UI project. The code works in developer system but in our build machine we are getting the following error in the line Database.SqlQuery(sqlQuery, parameters).ToList();
**An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but 
was not handled in user code**

and the Inner exception is

**Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbDispatchers.get_Connection()'.**

Please see the details of developer machine and build machine below

**Developer Machine**

Windows 7 Enterprise operating system (64 bit), Visual Studio Premium 2013 with Update 4, Entity Framework 6.0.2

**Build Machine**

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard operating system (64 bit), Visual Studio Premium 2013 with Update 2, Entity Framework 6.0.2

The only difference which I could notice is the Visual Studio update but unfortunately we can not update the build machine with update 4. Another observation is, on build machine I am able to connect to database using Entity Framework 6.0.2 in my console application. The issue comes only with my Coded UI project and on that build machine.

**Just to summarise the issue**

Coded UI is able to connect to database using EF 6.0.2 on developer machine.

Coded UI is *not* able to connect to database using EF 6.0.2 on build machine.

Console application is able to connect to database using EF 6.0.2 on build machine.

Please let me know anyone has come across this issue and please let me know the solution.

Thanks,

Deepak

Comment: Any differences in .Net versions/updates?

Comment: Yes, developer machine uses Visual Studio Premium 2013 with Update 4 and build machine uses Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 2. But unfortunately we will not able to update the build machine to Update 4.

Comment: Since EF 6.0.2 not working, I am using EF5.0 now to connect to database and it works with out any error.